# selenium giving "Message: no such window: target window already closed from unknown error: web view not found"

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

i have a selenium script with python which clicks a link and then switches to the tab the link has opened, this process needs to be repeated 3 times the first time it's fine i then do `driver.close()` to close the current active tab but in the second cycle i get this error:

```
File "main.py", line 50, in main
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="daily-sets"]/mee-card-group[1]/div/mee-card[2]/div/card-content/mee-rewards-daily-set-item-content/div/div[3]/a').click()
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchWindowException: Message: no such window: target window already closed
from unknown error: web view not found
```

the code is this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from data import *

def main():

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driverpath, options=options)
    driver.get(URL)

    #first
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="daily-sets"]/mee-card-group[1]/div/mee-card[1]/div/card-content/mee-rewards-daily-set-item-content/div/div[3]/a').click()
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
    time.sleep(30)
    driver.close()
    
    #second
    time.sleep(0.5)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="daily-sets"]/mee-card-group[1]/div/mee-card[2]/div/card-content/mee-rewards-daily-set-item-content/div/div[3]/a').click()
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
    time.sleep(30)
    driver.close()
    
    #third
    time.sleep(0.5)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="daily-sets"]/mee-card-group[1]/div/mee-card[3]/div/card-content/mee-rewards-daily-set-item-content/div/div[3]/a').click()
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
    time.sleep(30)
    driver.close()
```

Comment: driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1]) would switch to the last handle.

Comment: You also should switch to the handle 0 after you close a tab.

Comment: @arundeepchohan if i have 2 tabs doesn't it automatically returns to the one that isn't closed?

Comment: If you look at the error log you'd see it doesnt

Comment: the driver will be in no-mans land after that window closes.  (It'll be using a handle that no longer exists.)  You have to explicitly tell it to switch back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an easier way to loop 3 times click and go from tab to parent handle.

```
for i in range(1,4):
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="daily-sets"]/mee-card-group[1]/div/mee-card[{}]/div/card-content/mee-rewards-daily-set-item-content/div/div[3]/a'.format(i)).click()
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
    time.sleep(30)
    driver.close()
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
```